# Can't connect to RDP when RemoteFX enabled

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v, remotefx

I'm having problems connecting via RDP to the VM which has an active RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter. I can't see any problem in the Event log on VM with RemoteFX. I can't connect even via Enhanced session from Hyper-V host. I can connect from Hyper-V host only when no Enhanced Session is enabled.

During connection via RDP, I can see the session is being secured and then error occur: *"Your remote desktop services session has ended, possibly for one of the following reasons: Admin ended session...; Error occurred...; A network problem occurred"*

Do you have any idea what can be a reason why it's not working? Am I missing some feature/role in the VM? Or RemoteFX requires a licensed RDS host in order to work properly (can't be used 120 trial period)?

About my configuration:

**Hyper-V Host:**

- I have installed Windows Server 2016 DC (latest updates installed)
  and plugged in Nvidia GeForce 1050.
- Nvidia Drivers properly installed and shown in the device manager.
- I have installed Hyper-V role with Remote Desktop Virtualization Host
  so I can attach the RemoteFX graphic card to my VM (120 days trial of RDP licenses)

**VM:**

- Clean Windows 10 Enterprise 1909 Gen1. Properly showing in device
  manager display adapters "Microsoft RemoteFX Graphics Device - WDDM"
- Windows Firewall Turned Off (also tried with turned on + enabled RemoteFX rules)
- DXDiag.exe showing properly RemoteFX GPU

Comment: What happens when you open More Settings in RDP and reduce the Display Properties less intensive (Color Depth). Make sure no local resources are connected. In other words very plain vanilla RDP.  Does that help?

Comment: I tried to play with these settings and nothing helped the same issue. I also disabled all local connected resources but no luck.

Comment: I am not sure. Is the Video adapter in the Guest machine the VM hardware for the Video adapter in the Host?  Can you permanently set the Guest Video settings to something simpler?  That may be the only way to get RDP to work.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I have Physical GPU in Hyper-V Host and in VM is configured RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter with resolution and memory. What do you mean by _Guest Video settings_?

More in here: https://ibb.co/TvmjPtG https://ibb.co/SXp490L

Comment: I have not seen this before myself (I use RDP a lot). But you said disabling Remote FX allows RDP to work. I thought this perhaps could be disabled in the Guest. Otherwise I am not sure.

Comment: I tried to disable all my GPO's defined by domain on that Hyper-V host in case of misconfiguration, but no luck. This picture: https://ibb.co/MR6hcSm shows host screen when I try to connect via RDP (it's there for a while until error on my RDP client will appear). This picture https://ibb.co/wdzRcRP shows working session from hyper-v host when no enhanced session enabled. This picture https://ibb.co/5MTHdrv show attempt of hyper-v host to use enhanced session and is ended.

Comment: I do not know why this would occur or even if you can expect it to work. We use very simple graphics on Servers because that is all they need to do their work.

Comment: I can see. I tried also integrated one in CPU but same behavior. Not sure if Windows Server 2019 will help because it uses different technology I heard they dropped support for RemoteFX and use GPU-P.